# How to trigger focus to the Google Chrome address bar (OmniBox)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am making a Google Chrome extension that overrides the [New Tab](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override) (the page that appears when the user opens a new tab or window).

I want to trigger the focus on the Google's address bar on a button click. I've read the [chrome.omnibox docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox), but I haven't found a method that triggers its focus.

Is there a trick how I can do that?

Comment: Nope, there's no trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: **No!**

I've tried a million workarounds and tricks, but nothing helped.

My conclusion is that this action is considered to be a security (and privacy) vulnerability, and therefore is not allowed.